# Swift: Extract the current value of the user for a drawing ipad App

Tags: ios, ipad, switch-statement

I am developing an Ipad App which allowed to draw (using the touch screen) and the save the current position of the user (the lastPoint should be automatically saved in a cvs or text file).

I am a beginner in switch programming. The drawing app was easy but I have a problem to extract these number.

I am able to write the current position of the user in the console. So when the user draw the line the x and y coordinate of the last point are printed in the console. Now I am trying to save this point in csv file.

I need to know how and where (Viewcontroller/AppDelegate) I could write a function to collect these data.

Answer (score 0):

You should collate and draw these datapoints in the `viewController` that manages the view you intend to draw to.

In addition to this, rather than use .csv or some other flatfile format. I suggest you collect the datapoints in an array (easy to read/use as a datasource).

You can then serialize the array using `NSKeyedArchiver`/`NSCoding`, and write this 'frozen' object to the application documents folder.

Comment: Thank you it's a good idea! But my points are in the format CGFloat how to collect these data in a static array